# anonymous firebase accounts that never expire

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Anonymous Auth in my firebase webapp and today my uid changed. It just so happened to be 30 days since my anonymous account was created, so I am assuming that all anonymous account sessions expired after 30 days. [related](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/docs/v1/providers/anonymous.md#optional-settings)

Is there a way to have anonymous account sessions never expire?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the docs should work:

```
authClient.login("anonymous", {
  rememberMe: true
})
```

Comment: according to the code, it's either 30 days or 0 days https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/js/src/simple-login/Client.js#L213

Comment: You are right, I assumed the default was 30 days.. Seems like a built in security precaution

Answer (score 0):

You are using the legacy Firebase. The latest version of Firebase Auth anonymous accounts do not expire.

Comment: Can you provide the source of your statement?